# Can't remote access MySQL server running on Mac OS X

Tags: mysql-5, mac-os-x, errors

I have a MySQL server running on my work computer, which runs Mac OS X Maverick. I want to access it from home computer, which also has Mac OS Maverick.

From terminal, if in 1 tab, I ssh into my work computer and just let the ssh session sit there without being idle, then on another tab, I can access MySQL server.

However, without the ssh session running, I will get following error

> **ERROR 2003 (HY000):** Can't connect to MySQL server on 'SERVER_IP_ADDRESS' (60)

I've tried to modify `my.cnf` file on the server by commenting out bind-address or assigning it to `0.0.0.0` but it doesn't work.

Why is it like that? How can I configure the server so that it allows remote access without having to run ssh on the client? Can someone please help?

Comment: I have the same problem with PostGIS running on remote OS X...can connect to database when `ssh` is open in one tab, but otherwise not. I think the problem is that the database server process is paused or not running when I am not logged in to the remote server.

Answer (score 20):

I have been banging my head against this error today on OSX Yosemite with MySQL 5.7 recently updated with Homebrew. Following suggestions on StackOverflow and elsewhere, I hunted around after `my.cnf` files all of which specified `bind-address=0.0.0.0`. I even [removed and reinstalled MySQL following these instructions](https://gist.github.com/vitorbritto/0555879fe4414d18569d) and then reinstalled using `brew install mysql`. Still no remote connections allowed.

It wasn't until I ran `ps -ax | grep mysql` and noticed that the bind address was being passed in the launch command (thus overriding any `my.cnf` files) that I dug some more and found out [that Homebrew binds MySQL to 127.0.0.1 by default](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/28007).

Editing `~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist` to change `--bind-address=127.0.0.1` to `--bind-address=0.0.0.0` solved my problem (the latter should be changed to a specific IP address if this isn't just a development machine).

I feel this is a vital piece of information that was lacking from most of the resources I consulted so hopefully posting this here will help someone else!

**EDIT:** As [LeandroCR](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/100177/leandrocr) indicated in the comments, running `brew services restart mysql` will overwrite the plist file in LaunchAgents with the default one, leading to MySQL mysteriously refusing connections again. So better advice than what I originally wrote is the following:

1. Edit `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/<yourversion>/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist` and replace `--bind-address=127.0.0.1` with `bind-address=*` or `--bind-address=0.0.0.0` ([see MySQL documentation on bind-address](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address))
2. Restart mysql using `brew services restart mysql`

Then MySQL should continue to accept non-local connections from then on - until you reinstall it, presumably.

**Edit (Sep 2019)**
[Timothy Zorn](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/188959/timothy-zorn) points out that this problem no longer occurs for MySQL 8.x installed and run via Homebrew, so my answer above, written in 2016, may only be relevant to 5.x.

Comment: Another tip: If you are running $ brew services restart mysql it will cleanup the plist file from LaunchAgents every time. If you want to persist that change edit /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/<yourversion>/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist - Also Emma thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I've installed mysql 5.6 using `brew install mysql56`, and I changed bothe the `~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql56.plist` and `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql56/5.6.32/homebrew.mxcl.mysql56.plist` files. But still when I launch mysql through `mysql.server start`, the ps command shows that the `bind-address=127.0.0.1`. Is there any other files to edit?

Comment: @xi.lin As I understand it, `mysql.server start` bypasses the LaunchAgent, so it probably gets its setting from somewhere else. To use the setting in the `plist`, you probably have to use `brew services restart mysql`

Comment: @EmmaBurrows Using `brew services restart mysql` output `Successfully started `mysql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mysql)` but still the address is `127.0.0.1 `. Actually I couldnot find `homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist` instead of having `homebrew.mxcl.mysql56.plist`

Comment: Maybe you have more than one version of MySQL (I think I ended up in that situation once), in which case `brew services restart mysql56` might be the thing to do. That's all I can think of!

Comment: As of now this is no longer how it works. The command used to run `mysqld_safe` for me has no `bind_address`. Instead it is specified in `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf`.

Comment: Are you using Homebrew? I think `mysqld_safe` has always kept its `bind_address` in `my.cnf`. The problem I had was that Homebrew's `brew services start mysql` was overriding the `my.cnf` using a parameter in its plist file. Starting using `mysqld_safe` was fine.

Comment: another tip: `locate mysql.plist` was helpful.

Comment: brew no longer includes `--bind-address=127.0.0.1` in `homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist`. The correct answer for the current behavior is to edit `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf`

Comment: @TimothyZorn thanks for the update. I haven't had to deal with this for a while now due to using Docker instead! Do you know if this for MySQL 8.0 or does it also apply to 5.x?

Comment: Good question - I'm currently using 8.0. I'm not sure about 5.x

Answer (score 9):

Running `locate my.cnf` found the file `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf`

1. Edit that file and set `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`
2. Restart mysql: `brew services restart mysql`

Comment: This answer should be at the top

Answer (score 5):

I hope you need to create the user for remote access with `'%'` wildcard and grant permissions on DB's.

**Step 1:**

In my.cnf (https://serverfault.com/questions/9107/how-do-i-find-where-mysql-is-loading-its-config-from)
comment out your bind address

```
# bind-address        = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

And restart MySQL Server.

**Step 2:**

Then you need to grant permissions to user for remote access

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

Please have a look on [How to enable remote connection.](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html)

Comment: I've tried this setting (commenting out bind-address) before and it didn't work. I've created a user and granted all permission as well. `mysql> show grants for 'home';
| Grants for home@%                                                                                                              | GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'home'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '...' WITH GRANT OPTION |
`

Comment: Do you have any firewall in place ? If it is please disable that.

Comment: Yes, I can access the server when firewall is turned off. But can I configure the firewall to allow remote access to sql server rather than completely turn it off? On the server, in firewall settings, I've set **mysqld** to "allow incoming connections"

Comment: Do you have SQL Server also installed on same machine ?

Comment: Yes, I do. You mean SQL server and Firewall on the same machine?

Comment: I hope you can ask a separate question for this, I don't have experience with SQL Serevr

Comment: Actually, despite what I said in previous comment, I still get error when Firewall on the server is turned off. I thought it worked but it turns out I accessed MySQL server right before I closed the ssh session. I tried it again, after the ssh session closed and got the same error even when firewall had been turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Check iptables as
 iptables -L

If your IP is not present then add it

In case of Ubuntu ADD IP to allow access :

```
iptables -A ALLOWIN -s 192.168.1.XX/32 ! -i lo -j ACCEPT
```